# Why the Cantor set have $\mathfrak{c}$ subsets homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

Observe that ${^{2}({^{\omega}2})}\thickapprox{^{\omega}({^{\omega}2})}\thickapprox{^{\omega}2}$. Consequently, each Cantor set contains a family of $\mathfrak{c}$ pairwise disjoint Cantor sets. If the Cantor set $2^{\omega}$ contains at least one homeomorphic subset to $\mathbb{Q}$, then $2^{\omega}$ has at least $\mathfrak{c}$ homeomorphic subsets to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now, why is there at most $\mathfrak{c}$ homeomorphic subsets to $\mathbb{Q}$?

And how can I prove that $2^{\omega}$ has at least one homeomorphic subset to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Another way to find a subset homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q$ is to note that, as an ordered set, the Cantor set is the Dedekind completion of a set of order type $1+2\cdot\Bbb Q+1$, the set of endpoints of removed intervals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question is just a consequence of cardinal arithmetic: the number of subsets of size $\kappa$ of a set of size $\lambda$ is bounded above by the set of functions from $\kappa$ to $\lambda$, which is just $\lambda^\kappa$ - now observe that $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$.

In the other direction, note that $(1)$ every countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ (indeed, [any two countable dense linear orders without endpoints are isomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method#Application_to_densely_ordered_sets)), and $(2)$ the Cantor set is quite similar to $\mathbb{R}$ - specifically, $\mathbb{R}$ is the image of the Cantor set under a continuous map which is injective except on a countable set. This suggests that to find something $\mathbb{Q}$-like in the Cantor set we should start by considering arbitrary countable dense subsets of the Cantor set; can you find one, and determine whether it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Thank you! Your comment on the second question reminded me that any zero-dimensional space (for example $\mathbb{Q}$) can be imbedded in the Cantor's set (Corollary 1.5.7 - The infinite-dimensional topology of function spaces). Now I have everything.

Comment: @FernandoMauricioRiveraVega Unless I'm missing something, that's not right as stated - consider a discrete space of cardinality $>2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Oh! Clear. I forgot to mention that in chapter one of that book all topological spaces under discussion are separable and metrizable.